# Is it possible to write an inequality with two arguments to be evaluated on one side in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, inequalities

Is there a cleaner way of writing the following:

`(a > b) and (a > c)`

The following doesn't work, but this might illustrate the kind of thing I'm looking for:

`a > [b, c]`

Comment: If you're asking because you're writing many equalities as part of a case/switch, you *might* be looking for  the new pattern matching.  By grouping your matches you could avoid repeatedly testing for conditions.

Comment: all([a > x for x in [b,c]]) should do what you want. The all() function returns True if a is bigger than all elements in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```py
a > max(b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write `c < a > b`, but it's pretty weird-looking. Probably clearer simply with `a > b and a > c`.

Comment: ouch!  Yes, please don't write that. Pick 1 direction to read your code in and stick to it, but preferably pick left-to-right....